# What happens when I don't add [DataMember] to a field in [DataContract]?

Tags: c#

I am specifically interested in knowing that whether that particular field is serialised or not.

For example, I have:

```
[DataContract]
public class Node {
   [DataMember]
   public string Name;

   [DataMember]
   public int ID;
}
```

I am only interested in serialising the name, do I still need to decorate with `ID` with `DataMember` attribute?

Comment: With WCF in .NET 3.5 SP1 and newer, you can **leave out** all `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes and your class will be serialized just like the XML Serializer would - it will serialize all public properties. But if you do use some attributes, then anything you don't mark with `[DataMember]` is omitted and not serialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you omit the attribute the value will not be serialized.

So if you only need the name, you don't need to decorate the ID

Comment: In addition, it should be noted that if you don't mark ANY field/property with `DataMember`, they're all serialized.